# react mentions text area doesn't grow with text

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to implement [react mentions](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions) text area that starts with one row and if the user types enough text the text area height will grow with the text size, but when I'm using [MultipleTrigger example](https://github.com/signavio/react-mentions/blob/master/demo/src/examples/MultipleTrigger.js) and adding to default styles `height: "20px"` (to start with one line) the text area doesn't grow with the text... here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/2300p17zvn

when I'm trying to fix this with some javascript and adding height by myself you can see the that the text area is not acting as usual and when a line is added all the text goes up and then down here is an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7mrvon4vpj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `height` and set the appropriate `minHeight`

```
  input: {
      padding: 9,
      minHeight: 63,
      outline: 0,
      border: 0
    }
```

to

```
  input: {
      padding: 9,
      minHeight: 20,
      outline: 0,
      border: 0
    }
```

Check this [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n02w3v60x4)